# Assets display changed, cutting off folders

Tags: assets, field

I am not yet able to upgrade to Craft 4 due to some plugins used regularly not being ready, but on updating 3 to a newer version a few weeks ago, noticed the way asset folders were displayed - both on entry fields and in the assets section - has changed.

Is there a way to change this at all?

We have hundreds of folders, often with multiple sub-folders (think 'Names', 'A-Z', 'People', 'Events with those people') and finding the images we are looking for now takes several times as long in each instance - and in some instances colleagues say they can't even access the folder they require, so are re-uploading an existing asset instead. Not an ideal situation.

If there's a plugin, I'll be willing to try that - something that allows us to work as quickly as before this change was implemented!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to change this at all?

Assuming you're referring to the [Asset changes](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/v3/CHANGELOG.md#380---2023-03-08) that were released in Craft 3.8, then the answer is no, not without rolling back to 3.7.x.

If you're encountering bugs, or workflow enhancements you think should be made, I'd encourage you to either create an [issue for the former](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues) or a [discussion for the latter](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions), so they can be addressed.